# How do I pass AJAX (JS) value to this?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying for hours to do this simple thing but I don't seem to be able to. I am familiar quite a bit with PHP but JS and AJAX are alien to me.

So, what I'm trying to do is to pass simple value from form that I have. But first things first.

I am unable even to pass value here:

```
 function load_data(query)
 {
    var simple = "123";
  $.ajax({
   url:"pool/"+simple,
   data:{query:query},
   success:function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
```

How to get this done, even this simple part first? Have "simple" actually call

```
url:"pool/123",
```

If ever manage to do this I have a bit more complex question to answer. But I am even not able to do this... What I'm doing wrong here?

Everything else I managed to do, now I need page to be fetched by IDs and that would be like this simple 123 or I'll explain later how I can get them from "data-" values, but how to achieve this? What I'm doing wrong here.

EDIT:
Just to be clear, I'm trying just to pass value of variable here just as I'd do in PHP so that it can be "called" like that (fetch that URL). For example I'm trying to achieve this (sample in PHP below)

```
<?php $simpleSample = "123"; ?>
<script>
function load_data(query)
     {
      
      $.ajax({
       url:"pool/<?php echo $simpleSample; ?>",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data){
        $('#result').html(data);
       }
      })
     }
</script>
```

EDIT 2:
I managed to get somewhere... I think.

When I do now:

```
console.log($("#myFormName [name='simple']").val());
```

I get two values as result (so this is all good):

> 1212
>
> undefined

What I'm thinking is problem now is somehow with defining var as I do it like this:

```
var simple = $("#myFormName [name='simple']").val();
```

Yet it still does not work. **So, what I'm doing wrong to pass that value** to url: ?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the value `123` to a scipt called pool?

Comment: Could you please post the HTML part to have more details of context. So you don't know how to retrieve value from a data attribute ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I have modal that pops up that has values like this

'<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm editRecord" data-PoolID="'+data[i].PoolID+'">Edit</a>'

Comment: That modal works just fine when I am sending data over, but what is a problem is that I have other function "pool" that I would like to narrow down by let's say PoolID from this modal and I'm not able to do that for hours. Going crazy

Comment: And hwat is the value of query parameter of the function load_data ?

Comment: It loads data from this function

~~~
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
  var search = $(this).val();
  if(search != '')
  {
   load_data(search);
  }
  else
  {
   load_data();
  }
 });
~~~

Comment: It is pretty much text box that does the search query in DB

Answer (score 0):

Everything was working exactly as expected. So code above works just fine.

Problem was that I did testing for half a day now, when I searched for results it was inside of category that has no results (hence, no reply from server).

Anyway, it all works just with the code above.

Thanks to all who wanted to help.